Flipper Zero - ESPWebTool - Error: Couldn't sync to ESP. Try resetting
I'm trying to use ESPWebTool to flush new firmware for my Flipper Zero WiFi Board, yet getting following error (it's like Chrome can't connect to Flipper Zero via USB/serial)
Output
Click Connect to start
Connecting...
Connected successfully.
Try hard reset.
Error: Couldn't sync to ESP. Try resetting.

please advise
thanks!
